# ActionScript and Loading XML on HTTPS

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

How do i load XML over HTTPS if the flash file is being served over HTTP?

According to Adobe you just add the secure="false" attribute http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e08.html

```xml
<allow-access-from domain="www.example.com" secure="false" />
```

But it still doesn't load the XML when flash is served from HTTP. If served from HTTPS its not an issue.

Comment: um isn't that the point of HTTPS

Comment: sorry, can you elaborate. don't understand your comment

Comment: The point of anything on an HTTPS is to block calls for data that are not cert. However putting secure false in the crossdomain should have worked. Did you put it in the crossdomain on the HTTP or the HTTPS server. It has to be on the server the that data/XML is coming from. IE:HTTPS. Don't forget to use loadPolicy

Comment: Just so there is no confusion. The flash is on HTTP and requesting to load XML that is hosted on HTTPS. So its a non secure flash file requesting secure content

Comment: LoadPolicy is being used and the crossdomain file is on the HTTPS server

Comment: Did you verify the crossdomain is being loaded from the HTTPS?

Comment: yeah they are hitting the URL using HTTPS. I just found out the developer is using AS2. I looked up the documention for AS2 and its the same. I made a quick AS3 example and its works but in AS2 it doesn't. They cannot convert to AS3.

Comment: OH god AS2. I don't think it is possible in AS2. How about having the HTTP request the data from the HTTPS server using something like curl and make like a service.

Comment: Ok, working now. Looks like it turned out to be a caching issue. Perhaps Flash was caching the crossdomain file so even after the secure="false" was added it wasn't pulling it. Thanks for the help

Comment: Ahhh good job. You know if you put a time stamp at the end of your query string you can override the browser caching. XML usually gets cached to if you need it to update often just add it. like so example.com/somepage.php?cachebuster=1341234 even random numbers will work